# Eclipse STS - Out of memory

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

TRYING TO EDIT AS SUGGESTED:

STS crashes continously, here is an exmple of the last logs in projects folder:

```
...
...
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-10-31 08:41:50.924
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit)
    ...
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-10-31 08:41:58.932
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit)
    ...
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-10-31 08:42:00.869
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4720)
    ...
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-10-31 08:42:47.266
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
!SESSION 2021-10-31 08:43:56.477 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.202001211336-RELEASE
java.version=11.0.9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-10-31 08:44:07.942
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-10-31 08:44:07.942
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@2689b752,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@84eafc2,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2021-10-31 08:44:21.052
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\franc'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2021-10-31 08:46:43.793
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.properties.ProjectPropertyPage (bundle: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces, propertyPage: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.namespaces.projectPropertyPage)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-10-31 08:46:54.518
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1452)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Here's an example of one of the edited poms of the workspace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>microservices-demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.microservices.demo</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>kafka-producer</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microservices.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-config-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microservices.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

It began when I was comparing and modifying java, pom, and properties files outside STS using Winmerge

Comment: Please show the log not shortened starting with `!SESSION` and the `pom.xml`. Please note, an OutOfMemoryError can also be caused by an apparently unrelated plugin which you might have installed in your STS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the project (only from eclipse, don't check to option to delete from disk).
Then reimport in workspace solved the problem.